# How do I move my PC to a VM instance?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization, data-transfer

Is there a way for me to take my current PC and transfer it to a VM running on the same machine or another machine?

I am currently running Windows XP.

Comment: You'll get more/better answers if you post on http://superuser.com instead. :D

Comment: there too ... I just figure the IT pro site will get better results

Answer (score 5):

When using VMWare, there's a tool called [VMWare Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) that can make a VM image out of your machine.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something called P2V (physical to virtual) most VM solutions have it.  But you will get better responses on server fault.

Answer (score 1):

[XenConvert](http://www.citrix.com/contentproblem.asp?url=%2Fenglish%2Fss%2Fdownloads%2Fdetails%2Easp&qs=downloadId%3D1855017%26productId%3D683148) did an amazing job on converting out SVN\Build server to a vhd, and its free!

Comment: Found it here : http://www.citrix.com/English/ss/downloads/details.asp?downloadId=1857892&productId=683148&c1=pov1855414&c2=ost12723&c3=sot8218#top

Answer (score 1):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx  has a tool for converting a physical machine to virtual. Sysinternals has some good tools and you can try it for free, so not much to lose

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which VM you're using, but I've had some success using the [VMware P2V Assistant](http://www.vmware.com/download/p2v/). I have had a few HAL issues trying to boot (BSOD) images generated from P2V, but they can usually be resolved by removing most 3rd party drivers and replacing HAL.DLL and NTOSKRNL.DLL